# Very simple C# program generates a `NullReferenceException was unhandled` error

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration, datagridview

I have a simple WinForm that I'm using to try to help me with ADO.NET. 
It has a datagridview

I have added a compact sql server database to the project called `experiment.sdf`

In the App.config file I have added the following. I used a previous project app file to base this on so maybe there's an error in here?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DatabaseDGVexperiments.Properties.Settings.DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"
      connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\experiment.sdf"
      providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I've added a reference to the configuration library.

Behind the form is the following code:

```
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"].ConnectionString);
```

When it hits the line `SqlConnection conn = ...` I get an error `NullReferenceException was unhandled`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Make sure `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"].ConnectionString` is not null.

Comment: You calling `.ConnectionString` of a null reference. `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"]` does not return an object. The string specified does not match a string in the web.config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

```
name="DatabaseDGVexperiments.Properties.Settings.DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"
```

to:

```
name="DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"
```

or change this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"]
```

to:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseDGVexperiments.Properties.Settings.DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"]
```

Comment: I changed the config file. Now it errors on the line `myAdapt.Fill...` with an `SQLException was Unhandled`; A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: the sdf file is in the same project! why should it have difficulty connecting?

Comment: @whytheq: You need the SQL CE classes to use the SqlServerCe provider. Change SqlConnection to SqlCeConnection, and so on.

Comment: that worked a treat; I also had to change `SELECT * FROM experiment.dbo.helloworld` to `SELECT * FROM helloworld` for the code to work - why?

Comment: @whytheq: Becauase there are no databases and users (the first two parts of the xx.xx.xx notation), the SQL CE file is a single database, and you don't specify a user when you connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseDGVexperiments.Properties.Settings.DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"].ConnectionString
```

note that you need to give name as

`DatabaseDGVexperiments.Properties.Settings.DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg`

not as

`DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg`

### EDIT:

You need to use `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeDataAdapter` too work with SqlServerCe database, add reference to `System.Data.SqlServerCe` and then code should like below.

```
using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseDGVexperiments.Properties.Settings.DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var myAdapt = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM experiment.dbo.helloworld", conn))
    {
        DataSet mySet = new DataSet();
        myAdapt.Fill(mySet, "AvailableValues");
        DataTable myTable = mySet.Tables["AvailableValues"];
        this.uxExperimentDGV.DataSource = myTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the config file. Now it errors on the line `myAdapt.Fill...` with an `SQLException was Unhandled; A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.`

Comment: thanks Damith - `using` is a way to avoid persistent database activity?

Comment: Using statement handles the disposing object. you don't need to do it from code.

Answer (score 0):

You've used a different key value in your code then in web.config.  the strings need to match exactly.