# SQL Server CE string errors on .dbo. syntax

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

A following question to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961648/sql-server-compact-sdf-file-within-c-sharp-project-problems-with-sqlexception)

I'm using a SQL Server CE database included in the c# winforms project

The following does not work but if I amend the SQL string to

```
SELECT * FROM helloworld
```

then it does work. Why? Is there a full path that I could use

```
SELECT * FROM <blah>.<blah>.helloworld
```

?

```
using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseDGVexperiments.Properties.Settings.DatabaseDGVexperimentsConnStg"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var myAdapt = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM experiment.dbo.helloworld", conn))
    {
        DataSet mySet = new DataSet();
        myAdapt.Fill(mySet, "AvailableValues");
        DataTable myTable = mySet.Tables["AvailableValues"];
        this.uxExperimentDGV.DataSource = myTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? SQL CE doesn't have multiple schemas/catalogs like SQL Server

Comment: ok - so SqlCe only has a single db, therefore no further information will ever be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL CE doesn't have multiple schemas/catalogs like SQL Server (ref Thomas Levesque Jun 9)
Therefore no further information will ever be required in the `FROM` clause